# Does google pub/sub have concept of partition like kafka?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

What is the partition strategy if n subscriber is sharing 1 subscriptions for a topic in google pub/sub?

Is it round robin? Or does each subscriber guarantee to have a set of key if there is no rebalancing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create several subscriptions on a same topic with a [filter on the message attributes](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering) to only select a subset of messages.

You can't set partition based on the subscribers of a same subscription.

Comment: so if there is n subscriber, and m message, each subscriber should get roughly m/n messages regardless of key right? Assuming the process time for each message is the same time for all subscriber.

Comment: Yes, it's the target distribution. But it could take time to stabilise that state, according to the processing time of each subscriber, and the sustained message traffic that you have in your topic.

Answer (score 1):

PubSub lite has a concept of partitions it seems.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/topics#provisioning_capacity

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/subscribing#receiving_messages

> To receive messages from a Lite subscription, request messages from the Lite subscription. The client library automatically connects to the partitions in the Lite topic attached to the Lite subscription. If more than one subscriber client is instantiated, messages will be distributed across all clients. The number of partitions in the topic determines the maximum number of subscriber clients that can simultaneously connect to a subscription.